# rails - DRY up controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, metaprogramming, dry

I have a controller with a lot of code duplication such as:

```rb
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def action1
  end

  ...

  def actionN
  end
end
```

And basically each action do something like this:

```rb
def action
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.action(current_user)
    flash[:notice] = "#{custom string for this action}"
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Problem with your request"
  end
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

I thought about a method in ApplicationController that takes an array of symbols and generate the other methods, such as:

```rb
def self.action_for(*args)
   args.each do |method, string|
     define_method method.to_sym do
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.send method.to_sym
          flash[:notice] = string
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Problem with your request"
        end
        redirect_to root_url
     end
   end
end
```

And call in PostController:

```rb
action_for [:action1, "Congratulations!"], [:action2, "Cool action!"] ..
```

I think this solution is ugly, it makes the ApplicationController dirty and allow other controllers to call my actions.

Any idea to solve the code-duplication problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything too ugly in this solution.

To limit the logic to one controller, you can define `self.action_for` in PostController, instead of ApplicationController, and call it below its definition.

Note that you're already passing in first elements in pairs as symbols, so `to_sym` calls in `action_for` are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks dgutov, I think that I'll use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make a single action which will receive some extra parameter, like `msg`? Then you can take advantage of built-in I18n support:

```
def some_action
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.action(current_user)
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t("messages.#{params[:msg]}", default: "Wrong message type")
  else
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t("messages.problem")
  end
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Or maybe that makes sense to allow your `@post.action` to return some message for your notice?

Comment: Thanks jdoe,
the problem is that calling "action1" the controller calls "action1" on the model (and not always the same action).

E.g. there is an action called archive, that call @post.archive and it will archive my post.

Anyway this solve clevely the problem with a custum string.
Have I get it your solution?

Comment: @Andrea Didn't notice that. But you can achieve it using `@post.send`+`params[:msg]`, as you did before. Just make sure that malicious user won't be able to trigger some unallowed action.

Comment: umh, I'll explore this solution!